# OneWay event logging on WCF block the thread

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, callback, oneway

I'd like to log some actions using OneWay events on WCF callback channel

I've got several methods like:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void LogSomething(String txt);
```

on my callback channel.
I'm iterating over every subscribed logger instance to send a message, but the whole application hangs up if one of them will not disconnect properly and won't close channel connection. Then even checking:

```
((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened
```

returns true so I can't even check if the channel is not broken.

`ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` are already set.

What is the best way to handle this? I'm using .NET 4.0

From my research I need to set `AsyncPattern` to `true` and change my code to:

```
[OperationContractAttribute(OneWay=true, AsyncPattern=true)]
IAsyncResult BeginLogSomething(String txt, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

void EndLogSomething(IAsyncResult result);
```

but is there a better way of doing it? If it's possible I would like NOT to change the code on the client side - I still would like to use `SynchronizationContext` and handle messages one by one.

Do I need to create a separate thread that will send messages in a queue?

Comment: Do you dispose the client after sending a single message ? or you use same WCF Client (proxy) for all messages?